# Reset IRB Console

Tags: ruby, console

How does one go about saying goodbye to all constants, objects, and the like defined *in* an `irb` session to return to a clean slate? By "*in*", I mean without manipulating subsessions.

Comment: Quit and restart? `irb` isn't exactly heavy weight enough to worry about restarting it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Type

```
exec($0)
```

in your irb console session.

Comment: +1 LOL, awesome answer. And save a character and your shift key with `exec $0`

Comment: `exec __FILE__` would be better since it reload any scripts pulled in with IRB too: give `exec $0` in `rails console`, and you'll see what I mean. However, these commands don't maintain any options that were passed when executing `irb` (e.g. `irb --prompt simple`), and they'll both fail in a subsession.

Comment: Pretty clever. Of course I'm not sure if this is faster than CTRL+D, ↑, enter.

Comment: Perhaps this might be of some help to you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749476/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-irb-if-i-dont-specify-programfile

Making a custom irb might be the only way to do it.

Comment: Customization did work; a custom IRB altogether would have been overkill. I ended up adding a function to `irbrc` that creates/destroys isolated namespaces wherein I can play.

Answer (score 3):

i am using fedora 16, exec $0 do not work for me. but i found the the way below:

CTRL+L or system("clear") or system("reset")

Comment: `system("command")` actually executes the `command` in a subshell. The man pages tell us that `clear` will simply "clear the terminal screen". While `reset` comes with a few more bells and whistles, it still yields only a superficial change. Anything instantiated in the IRB session still lives on in memory. Sunny J's suggestion cleverly executes the command used to jump into IRB in the first place. I'm a bit puzzled, however,  why you had trouble.  What output do you see on `puts $0`?