# Anyway to reload the modified gem files in the REPL

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, read-eval-print-loop

While trying to build a Ruby gem (using Bundler), I tend to test the code using the REPL provided by Bundler - accessible via `bundle console`.

Is there any way to reload the entire project in it? I end up loading individual (changed) files again to test the new change.

Comment: Can you try [something similar here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271676/reset-irb-console) ?

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Jikku were you able to solve this i'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: No it didn't, got busy with few other pressing things that I just managed control the annoyance for some time. Seems, I need to learn about how exactly Ruby loads files to figure this out.

Comment: You can try [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23677820/1949195)?

Answer (score 1):

The following hack works for a relatively simple gem of mine and Ruby 2.2.2. I'll be curious to see if it works for you. It makes the following assumptions:

1. You have the conventional folder structure: a file called `lib/my_gem_name.rb` and a folder `lib/my_gem_name/` with any files / folder structure underneath.
2. All the classes you want to reload are nested within your top module `MyGemName`.

It will probably not work if in one of the files under `lib/my_gem_name/` you monkey-patch classes outside of your MyGemName namespace.

If you're good with the assumptions above, put the following code inside the module definition in `lib/my_gem_name.rb` and give it a try:

```
module MyGemName

  def self.reload!
    Reloader.new(self).reload
  end

  class Reloader
    def initialize(top)
      @top = top
    end

    def reload
      cleanup
      load_all
    end

    private

    # @return [Array<String>] array of all files that were loaded to memory
    # under the lib/my_gem_name folder. 
    # This code makes assumption #1 above.  
    def loaded_files
      $LOADED_FEATURES.select{|x| x.starts_with?(__FILE__.chomp('.rb'))}
    end

    # @return [Array<Module>] Recursively find all modules and classes 
    # under the MyGemName namespace.
    # This code makes assumption number #2 above.
    def all_project_objects(current = @top)
      return [] unless current.is_a?(Module) and current.to_s.split('::').first == @top.to_s
      [current] + current.constants.flat_map{|x| all_project_objects(current.const_get(x))}
    end

    # @return [Hash] of the format {Module => true} containing all modules 
    #   and classes under the MyGemName namespace
    def all_project_objects_lookup
      @_all_project_objects_lookup ||= Hash[all_project_objects.map{|x| [x, true]}]
    end

    # Recursively removes all constant entries of modules and classes under
    # the MyGemName namespace
    def cleanup(parent = Object, current = @top)
      return unless all_project_objects_lookup[current]
      current.constants.each {|const| cleanup current, current.const_get(const)}
      parent.send(:remove_const, current.to_s.split('::').last.to_sym)
    end

    # Re-load all files that were previously reloaded
    def load_all
      loaded_files.each{|x| load x}
      true
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't want this functionality to be available in production, consider monkey-patching this in the `bin/console` script, but make sure to change the line `$LOADED_FEATURES.select{|x| x.starts_with?(__FILE__.chomp('.rb'))}` to something that will return a list of relevant loaded files given the new location of the code.

If you have a standard gem structure, this should work:
`$LOADED_FEATURES.select{|x| x.starts_with?(File.expand_path('../../lib/my_gem_name'))}` (make sure to put your monkey patching code before the `IRB.start` or `Pry.start`)