# Ruby - create gem: reload console with updated gem content

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rakefile

According to this [article](http://erniemiller.org/2014/02/05/7-lines-every-gems-rakefile-should-have/), we can test around our gem code by adding those lines to our rakefile:

```
task :console do
  require 'irb'
  require 'irb/completion'
  require 'my_gem' # You know what to do.
  ARGV.clear
  IRB.start
end
```

It works really well, except that whenever a change is made to the gem, I need to `exit` and rerun `rake console` to get the code updated. It is really not convenient as a creation/debugging tool ...

Is there a way to write a custom method that would act as the awesome `reload!` method from Rails?

A bash script won't work as the first command is in the Ruby console, and I'd rather have a 100% ruby solution.

Thanks!

Comment: `load 'whatever_file_that_was_changed.rb'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `$LOADED_FEATURES` global to find the components of your gem and re-load them using the `load` command (using `require` won't work, as it skips items that Ruby has already processed):

```
task :console do
  require 'irb'
  require 'irb/completion'
  require 'my_gem' # You know what to do.

  def reload!
    # Change 'my_gem' here too:
    files = $LOADED_FEATURES.select { |feat| feat =~ /\/my_gem\// }
    files.each { |file| load file }
  end

  ARGV.clear
  IRB.start
end
```

Note this will fail if you are writing native extensions, you'll have to exclude them, and you'll want a compile step and to exit/re-start anyway if they change.

Comment: Added a variable to get the gem name from `my_gem.gemspec`: `@gemname = Dir["#{Dir.pwd}/*.gemspec"].first.split('/').last.sub('.gemspec', '')`